# При добавлении свойства (no-repeat) background-image перестаёт показывать фон.(без этого свойства картинка выводится)

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<article class="block">
    <section class="sec1 flex"></section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    margin-top: 2px;
    background-image: url("../img/f1.jpg");
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.block {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #572c21;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

header h2,span {
    color: #c0893f;
}


nav {
    height: 65px;
}

nav .menu {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #c0893f;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c0893f;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.razdel {
    padding: 10px;
}

article {
    min-height: 400px;
}

section{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 420px;
}

article .sec1{
    background-image: url(../img/f3.jpg) no-repeat;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Речь идёт о секции с классом .sec1, забыл указать в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашёл ошибку, нужно было написать вместо background-image - просто background, для обобщения свойств.

Comment: На ошибку указали в комментарии)

Answer (score 0):

либо

```
background: url(../img/f3.jpg) no-repeat;
```

либо

```
background-image: url(../img/f3.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

так как в background-image нужно указывать только ссылку на изображение, поэтому и перестает выводится